# Python ZipFle DeFlated

Tags: python

How I can turn compression=ZIP_DEFLATED  on?
Thank you

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

zipObj = ZipFile('sample1.zip', 'w')

# Add multiple files to the zip
zipObj.write('ex3.py')
zipObj.write('ex6.py')
zipObj.write('ex7.py')
# close the Zip File
zipObj.close()
  
print('All files zipped successfully!')
```

Comment: Default setting is compression=ZIP_STORED. My files are not compressed in my zip archive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the compression method. It defaults to `ZIP_STORED`, which stores the files without compressing them. Do it like this:

```
import zipfile

zipObj = zipfile.ZipFile('sample1.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) # for python 2
zipObj = zipfile.ZipFile('sample1.zip', 'w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) # for python 3
```

or you can just import the sub classes:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile, ZIP_DEFLATED

zipObj = ZipFile('sample1.zip', 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED) # for python 2
zipObj = ZipFile('sample1.zip', 'w', compression=ZIP_DEFLATED) # for python 3
```

Make this change and you program will work.

Comment: Please add the error and just to be clear, none of them work?

Comment: I got this error   NameError: name 'ZIP_DEFLATED' is not defined

Comment: I made an edit, made a silly mistake, check now

Comment: python 2 has this error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./compress.py", line 6, in <module>
    zipObj = ZipFile('sample1.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
NameError: name 'zipfile' is not defined

Comment: i still have error zipObj = ZipFile('sample1.zip', 'w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
NameError: name 'zipfile' is not defined

Comment: Okay, I see the problem, I wrote the answer as if the import staement is `import zipfile`, yours is `from zipfile import Zipfile`, so, just remove the `zipfile.` from everywhere. Read mine and your import statement carefully and see the difference. You are importing the class Zipfile, I am importing the entire module zipfile.

Comment: What do you mean by remove zipfile from everywhere? Thank you

Comment: See my code and try it like that, instead of `from zipfile import Zipfile`, try it like I did it, If you want to keep it like yours remove `zipfile.`, notice the dot. But after this you also have to seperately import ZIP_DEFLATED.